# Can Semaphore use the double check locking idiom safely?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, semaphore

Is the following Thead Safe in java?

```
public class TestDCL{
    private static final Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1);
    private Object instance;

    public Object m(){
        if(instance == null){
            lock.acquire();
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new Object();
            }
            lock.release();
        }
        return instance; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, it depends. Is your `instance` mutable or immutable? If `instance` contains mutable state then you must declare it to be `volatile`. The reason you must due this has nothing to do with partially constructed objects as @Vijay Mathew suggests, but instead to do with thread visibility. Changes made to the state of your singleton instance in one thread will not necessarily be visible to another thread. Using the `volatile` keyword ensures that the hardware will use some mechanism to flush the cache to eliminate stale data.

Java Concurrency in Practice, chapter 16.2.3 outlines Safe initialization idioms and contains a lazy initialization idiom. 16.2.4 discusses the double-check locking idiom.

Comment: The `volatile` solution only works for J2SE5 and above. The most portable (i.e across several versions of the JVM) solution is still to use a static class to do the initialization.

Answer (score 2):

This is not thread-safe. The statement `new Object();` is not an atomic operation. `instance` ceases to be `null` when memory is allocated for it. A new thread that arrives at the first `if` condition after memory is allocated for `instance`, but before its constructor is called will return a partially constructed object. If you are trying to implement a thread-safe singleton, use [Bill Pugh's solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) which is both thread-safe and lazy.

Comment: -1: Your statement regarding how `new` works and variable assignment is incorrect.

Comment: I am not a Java expert, but I believe Vijay's statement is correct. `instance` can definitely be assigned **before** the constructor is ran according to the memory model of Java. And, of course, it cannot possibly be atomic because any number of operations could be performed in the constructor.

Comment: @Brian Gideon, I am pretty sure that Java still follows the basic rules for expression evaluation even when creating new objects. That is to say, for `=` everything on the right must be evaluated before that operator can be evaluated. Including, allocating space, initializing variables, and running the constructor code. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html

Comment: @Tim: The Java spec (§17.4.3) calls that program order. But, it seems the spec allows for the reordering of instructions as long as the sequential consistency property is maintained from the perspective of the current thread. The compiler is free to reorder any of the instructions as long as the current thread perceives them to have happened in program order (sequential consistency). So it seems that the Java spec allows for the assignment of `instance` before the constructor runs since that would not falsify sequential consistency from the current thread's persepctive.

Comment: @Tim: Sections §17.4.4 (Synchronization Order) and §17.4.5 (Happens-before Order) seem to drive this point home and the discussion points specifically mention that the construction of objects can be delayed as long as that fact is never observed from *that* thread. I admit, section §17.4 (Memory Model) is very confusing. And again, I'm more of a C# guy so take this with a grain of salt. For what is worth, Vijay's statement is 100% correct in C#.

Comment: @Brian Gideon, Okay, I agree, nothing in the specification states the ordering across threads. At least, I couldn't find any happens-before relationships. However, given that construction is not guaranteed, I am hesitant to think that an implementation might allow another thread access to a memory location which it might have to subsequently free due to failure during construction. Lesson learned? Use `volatile` or `synchronized` as they ensure a happens-before relationship.

Comment: Also, while discussing this with a coworker, I realized I am over-emphasizing thread-safety in the use of the Singleton while most of the time only the construction is discussed when in context of the pattern. That is to say, I am hypothesizing about the mutability/immutability of the implementation of the object which is intended to be made a Singleton rather than strictly enforcing the Singleton pattern.

Comment: @Tim, yep `volatile` or `synchronized` definitely fix the ordering problem as perceived from *other* threads...at least they do in later versions of Java. I think the earlier Java versions had weaker `volatile` semantics. And again, I could be speaking out of turn since Java is not my expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with previous posts from Tim. Volatile makes for visibility and the reason double check locking has been described as [clever but broken](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html) is around partially constructed objects (cache coherence/JVM optimisations).

It's all in the Goetz book as Tim suggests but I wanted to raise a point around lazy initialisation. Why do it? In my experience its generally not needed and it you're running in a multithreaded context and really concerned about intialisation safety - you've introduced a lot of variability and complexity which is really hard to test.

I'd also emphasis the old warning not to optimise early. Do you know for a fact that coarse grained synchronisation slows the app down? Usually, its the contention of locks that is slow not the syncrhonization keyword per-sa. A quick test with syncrhonized and DCL would confirm.